# Multiple Sticky Elements Jquery Sticky Float

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I was wondering how and if it would be possible to have multiple stickyfloat elements that follow each other up.

For instance, I have multiple articles with big images in them, i want to have the description stuck until you reach the next article. Currently all the stickyfloat elements start being sticky when the first one is... Here is the demo http://ckdt.net/code/

I used this code:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".post header" ).each(function() {
        $(this).stickyfloat( { duration: 400 } );
    });
});
```

Comment: The twitter bootstrap library have already done it. You can give it a try to scrollSpy: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-usage

Comment: Why should i use scrollspy? I don't want to have a navigational element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $( ".post" ).each(function() {
        $(this).find('header').stickyfloat( { duration: 400 } );
    });
});
```

Try like this. If this didn't work. Please a post fiddle with your code. So we can see what actually you have done there.

Comment: I've checked the fiddle. code is working fine right ? So what else you need to do there ?